# Colorir linhas de jTable pronta

Tags: java, jtable

Tenho um código e preciso fazer algumas melhorias, mas não estou conseguindo inserí-las corretamente, sou iniciante e tenho algumas dificuldades.

O software possui:

- uma class BeansCliente com os get e set;
- uma class BeansTabela; construtor AbstractTableModel do tipo `arrays`
- um método para preencher a tabela do tipo `String sql`

Não estou conseguindo inserir a condição para colorir as linhas.
Alguém pode ajudar?

Murillo, como solicitou segue as informações:

//modelo da jTable

```
public void preencherTabela(String Sql) {
        ArrayList dados = new ArrayList();
        String [] colunas = new String []{"Matricula","Ativo","Nome","Data Matric.","Data Vencimento","Janeiro","Fevereiro","Março","Abril","Maio","Junho","Julho","Agosto","Setembro","Outubro","Novembro","Dezembro"};
        conex.conexao();
        conex.executaSql(Sql);
        try {
            conex.rs.first();            
            do{
               dados.add(new Object[]{conex.rs.getInt("id_cd"),conex.rs.getString("ativo_cd"),conex.rs.getString("nome_cd"),conex.rs.getString("dtmat_cd"),conex.rs.getString("dtvenc_cd"),conex.rs.getString("jan_cd"),conex.rs.getString("fev_cd"),conex.rs.getString("mar_cd"),conex.rs.getString("mai_cd"),conex.rs.getString("jun_cd"),conex.rs.getString("jul_cd"),conex.rs.getString("ago_cd"),conex.rs.getString("set_cd"),conex.rs.getString("out_cd"),conex.rs.getString("nov_cd"),conex.rs.getString("dez_cd")}); 
            }while(conex.rs.next()); 
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Erro ao preencher arraylist"+ex);
        }
        BeansTabela modelo = new BeansTabela(dados, colunas);

        jTableCadCliente.setModel(modelo);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(65);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(50);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(170);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(100);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(100);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(60);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(60);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(60);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(60);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setPreferredWidth(60);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setPreferredWidth(60);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setPreferredWidth(60);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(12).setPreferredWidth(60);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(12).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(13).setPreferredWidth(60);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(13).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(14).setPreferredWidth(60);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(14).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(15).setPreferredWidth(60);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(15).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(16).setPreferredWidth(60);
        jTableCadCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(16).setResizable(true);
        jTableCadCliente.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        jTableCadCliente.setAutoResizeMode(jTableCadCliente.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        jTableCadCliente.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        //jTableCadCliente.setBackground(Color.ORANGE); //


        conex.desconecta();
    }

 //abaixo o metodo de seleção:

public BeansCliente filtro(BeansCliente mod) {
        conex.conexao();
        conex.executaSql("select *from clientesmilfe where nome_cd like'%"+mod.getPesquisa()+"%'");
        try {
            conex.rs.first();
            mod.setId(conex.rs.getInt("id_cd"));
            mod.setAtivo(conex.rs.getString("ativo_cd"));
            mod.setNome(conex.rs.getString("nome_cd"));
            mod.setDataMatricula(conex.rs.getString("dtmat_cd"));
            mod.setDataVencimento(conex.rs.getString("dtvenc_cd"));
            mod.setJaneiro(conex.rs.getString("jan_cd"));
            mod.setFevereiro(conex.rs.getString("fev_cd"));
            mod.setMarco(conex.rs.getString("mar_cd"));
            mod.setAbril(conex.rs.getString("abr_cd"));
            mod.setMaio(conex.rs.getString("mai_cd"));
            mod.setJunho(conex.rs.getString("jun_cd"));
            mod.setJulho(conex.rs.getString("jul_cd"));
            mod.setAgosto(conex.rs.getString("ago_cd"));
            mod.setSetembro(conex.rs.getString("set_cd"));
            mod.setOutubro(conex.rs.getString("out_cd"));
            mod.setNovembro(conex.rs.getString("nov_cd"));
            mod.setDezembro(conex.rs.getString("dez_cd"));
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente não cadastrado!");
        }
        conex.desconecta();
        return mod;
    }
```

Segue as informações complementares

jTable:

```
package modeloBeans;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

/**
 *
 * @author anild
 */
public class BeansTabela extends AbstractTableModel{

    //arrayslist é uma coleção que pode armazenar qualquer tipo de objeto
    //ela é um vetor do tipo string
    private ArrayList linhas= null;
    private String[] colunas= null;
//abaixo vamos criar o metodo 
public BeansTabela(ArrayList lin, String[] col) {
    setLinhas(lin);
    setColunas(col);
}    

    public BeansTabela() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    BeansTabela(String profissional_1, int i, String contador, double d) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    BeansTabela(BeansTabela tabc) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    /**
     * @return the linhas
     */
    public ArrayList getLinhas() {
        return linhas;
    }

    /**
     * @param linhas the linhas to set
     */
    public void setLinhas(ArrayList linhas) {
        this.linhas = linhas;
    }

    /**
     * @return the colunas
     */
    public String[] getColunas() {
        return colunas;
    }

    /**
     * @param colunas the colunas to set
     */
    public void setColunas(String[] colunas) {
        this.colunas = colunas;
    }
    //DAQUI PARA BAIXO É PARA EVITAR ERROS NOS METODOS CRIADOS ACIMA
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colunas.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return linhas. size();
    }
    /**
    *o metodo e o parametro int numCol é para pegar o nome da coluna
     * @param numCol
     * @return 
    */
    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int numCol){
        return colunas[numCol];
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param numLin
     * @param numCol
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int numLin, int numCol) {
        Object[] linha = (Object[])getLinhas().get(numLin);
        return linha[numCol];
    }

}
```

Condição é a data de vencimento em atraso;

Comment: Por favor adicione um **[mcve]** da sua jtable com alguns dados de exemplo para testes e que tipo de condição a linha seria colorida.

Comment: Esse código que você adicionou não ajuda muito a entender o problema e nem a chegar numa solução. Além de não ser um [mcve]. Você também não diz que condição deve colorir a linha.

Comment: O diegofm, explique pra mim o que é para você um ""um exemplo minimo, completo e verificavel"", porque o weibe entendeu e respondeu ajudando, agora você fica escrendo isso e não ajuda cara, qual a sua, o que você quer, o codigo completo, é isso que é um exemplo para você, como o outro conseguiu ajudar e você ai em toda a sua sabedoria fica escrevendo a mesma coisa e não ajuda em nada

Comment: Verificável é que possa ser facilmente reproduzido, ou seja vc tem que criar uma versão simplificada do teu código para que possamos reproduzir o problema apenas copiando o código e colocando para rodar, o link que o Diego colocou http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve já explica isto ;)

Comment: esse foi o código depois de pronto:   
Color c = Color.GREEN; Object text = table.getValueAt(row, 1); if (text != null && "SIM".equals(text.toString())) c = Color.RED; comp.setBackground(c);  o importante para eu aqui, é aprender, status não.

Comment: Olá, para concluir o tópico você deve aceitar uma resposta, dê uma olhada aqui mais sobre o assunto: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3117

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para colorir a linha você deve criar um DefaultTableCellRenderer.

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer tableCellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
             Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
             comp.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
             comp.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
             return comp;
        }
    };
jTableCadCliente.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, tableCellRenderer);
```

Comment: Obrigado Weibe, isso foi uma resposta simples e objetiva, muito bom..

Comment: Weibe o exemplo que passou funcionou perfeitamente, estou criando a condição, que no caso é ( pegar o valor da coluna 1 e se o valor for uma string "" ele retorna uma cor senão outra) em cima desse modelo que enviou fiz assim:

Comment: Dentro do modelo que você enviou implementei a condiçao, mas não certo:                                                                 
        Object ref = table.getValueAt(column, 1);
             if (column = "SIM"){
                 comp.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
                 comp.setForeground(Color.red);
             }else{
                 comp.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
                 comp.setForeground(Color.black);
             }

Comment: O correto é **Object ref = table.getValueAt(row, 1);** dessa forma forma você vai pegar a coluna 1 de cada linha da sua tabela.

Comment: vou corrigir e testar

Comment: Color c = Color.GREEN;
                    Object text = table.getValueAt(row, 1);
                        if (text != null && "SIM".equals(text.toString()))
                        c = Color.RED;
                        comp.setBackground(c);                                                    Deu certo, valeu sua ajuda!!